# deeplink always open the play store even app is install

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, deep-linking

i am using firebase dynamic link and it is working in google chrome , messenger , whatsapp but not working in facebook browser it is opening play store

my code to create dynamic link

```
  Future<String> _createDynamicLink(id) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: "http://applic.page.link",
      link: Uri.parse("https://applic.page.link/heloo"),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: com.examole.myapp,
        minimumVersion: 0,
      ),
      dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
        shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.short,
      ),
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: 'com.google.FirebaseCppDynamicLinksTestApp.dev',
        minimumVersion: '0',
      ),
    );

    Uri url;

    final ShortDynamicLink shortLink = await parameters.buildShortLink();
    url = shortLink.shortUrl;

    setState(() {
      _linkMessage = url.toString();
    });
    return _linkMessage;
  }
```

---

my code to fetch the link

```
void initDynamicLinks() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
    if (deepLink != null) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HelooPage()));
    }
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
      final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
      if (deepLink != null) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HelooPage()));
      }
    }, 
onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('onLinkError');
      print(e.message);
    });
  }
```

i use flutter android studio